# cassandra stress test results showing dropped performance in C* version 4.1.3 compare to 4.0.5

Tags: database-design, linux, cassandra, nosql, datastax-enterprise

we are planning to upgrade our cassandra cluster running on version 4.0.5 to 4.1.3.

Before upgrade, we performed stress-test on both version.

steps we followed :-

- created 3 node cassandra cluster with C* version 4.0.5 and java 8. kept values of all parameter in config files same as prod setup.
- Performed cassandra-stress test (write,read,mixed,counter_write and counter_read).
- Upgraded this cluster to 4.1.3, deleted the existing data (counter1 and standard1 tables and keyspaces1), removed sstable files and performed stress test again.

Result :

we have seen drop in  performance for almost every operation but in case of counter_write there was a drop of approx 20%.

Did anyone face the same issue ?